# CSS nesting has not been configured correctly error after upgrade TailwindCSS version 1 to 3

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, postcss, postcss-loader, tailwind-3

I am getting following error after upgrade tailwindcss from V1 to V3 although I have added `@tailwindcss/nesting` and `postcss-nesting`

[image]

My `postcss.config.js` has tailwind config

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {
            config: './tailwind.config.js'
        }
    }
};
```

and `tailwind.config.js` has

```
plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss-rtl'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('@tailwindcss/nesting')(require('postcss-nesting')),
]
```

Not sure why nesting plugin not working am I missing anything I am using Vue 3.

Answer (score 0):

Why not follow the guide, the error point to?

Import the nesting plugin in `postcss.config.js`, not in `tailwind.config.js`.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting

Comment: I did but it throws this error `Syntax Error: Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss/nesting requires PostCSS 8`

Comment: Then upgrade to PostCSS 8.

Comment: Already upgrade to PostCSS 8 but still same error